# concatenate data frame by column by month in R

Tags: r, plyr

I want to combine 2 data frame into one by column. My data looks like:

```
     station build   Year Month  
    1   Bariko 24.5  1961     1      
    2   Bariko 29.1  1962     1       
    3   Bariko 26.4  1963     1       
    4   Bariko 29.0  1961     2       
    5   Bariko 22.0  1962     2      
    6   Bariko 25.9  1963     2       
    7   Bariko 24.2  1961     3       
    8   Bariko 23.9  1962     3       
    9   Bariko 24.4  1963     3       
    10  Bariko 24.0  1961     4      
    11  Bariko 24.2  1962     4      
    12  Bariko 24.8  1963     4
```

I calculate the mean of build by month. I can name it after "mean".

```
    newdata=aggregate(build ~ station +Month, data=data, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

1) I want to combine "data" and "newdata"( with 4 rows corresponding to my 4 months) in order to have a data frame of 12 rows and 5 columns (I can repeat mean value for each month).

2) Create a new column of value corresponding to the difference between column 2 and column 5  (data$build-data$mean). At the end I will have data of 6 columns (station,build,year,month,mean,difference). Finally I can plot the difference by year.

Thank you,

Comment: `ave` could make this a bit easier `dat$mn <- with(dat, ave(build ,  list(station, Month), FUN=mean) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this with `dplyr`:

```
station = "Bariko"
build = c(24.5, 29.1, 26.4, 29, 22, 25.9, 24.2, 23.9, 24.4, 24, 24.2, 24.8)
Year = c(1961,1962,1963)
Month = rep(1:4, each=3)
df<-data.frame(station,build,Year,Month)
df
```

dplyr makes these kinds of things very simple:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  mutate(mean=mean(build)) %>%
  mutate (diff= build-mean)



   station build Year Month     mean        diff
1   Bariko  24.5 1961     1 26.66667 -2.16666667
2   Bariko  29.1 1962     1 26.66667  2.43333333
3   Bariko  26.4 1963     1 26.66667 -0.26666667
4   Bariko  29.0 1961     2 25.63333  3.36666667
5   Bariko  22.0 1962     2 25.63333 -3.63333333
6   Bariko  25.9 1963     2 25.63333  0.26666667
7   Bariko  24.2 1961     3 24.16667  0.03333333
8   Bariko  23.9 1962     3 24.16667 -0.26666667
9   Bariko  24.4 1963     3 24.16667  0.23333333
10  Bariko  24.0 1961     4 24.33333 -0.33333333
11  Bariko  24.2 1962     4 24.33333 -0.13333333
12  Bariko  24.8 1963     4 24.33333  0.46666667
```

Answer (score 2):

To demonstrate an alternative in base R (incorporating elements of what @user20650 suggested in comments), `within` + `ave` would make a good team here. `ave` can take different functions, but the default is `mean`, so you don't need to specify an aggregation function.

```
within(df, {
  Mean <- ave(build, station, Month)
  Diff <- Mean - build
})
#    station build Year Month        Diff     Mean
# 1   Bariko  24.5 1961     1  2.16666667 26.66667
# 2   Bariko  29.1 1962     1 -2.43333333 26.66667
# 3   Bariko  26.4 1963     1  0.26666667 26.66667
# 4   Bariko  29.0 1961     2 -3.36666667 25.63333
# 5   Bariko  22.0 1962     2  3.63333333 25.63333
# 6   Bariko  25.9 1963     2 -0.26666667 25.63333
# 7   Bariko  24.2 1961     3 -0.03333333 24.16667
# 8   Bariko  23.9 1962     3  0.26666667 24.16667
# 9   Bariko  24.4 1963     3 -0.23333333 24.16667
# 10  Bariko  24.0 1961     4  0.33333333 24.33333
# 11  Bariko  24.2 1962     4  0.13333333 24.33333
# 12  Bariko  24.8 1963     4 -0.46666667 24.33333
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, Mean := mean(build), by = Month]
dt[, Diff := Mean - build]
```

With `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
df <- ddply(df, "Month", transform, Mean = mean(build))
df$Diff = with(df, Mean - build)
```

Comment: @510947, if you want to suggest an improvement to this answer, do it in comments, not by forcing it into the answer itself

Comment: Well ok.. then there you go- for your second example you can use mutate, which will save you a step, like this `ddply(df,.(Month),mutate,mean=mean(build),diff=build-mean)`